# How fit should I become to pursue boxing?

Tags: exercise, boxing, training, self-training

I have been interested in joining a boxing gym for quite some time now. I have narrowed it down to a few gyms, and before I go choose which gym I would like to join I would first like to increase my fitness as to maximize the benefit I get from joining the gym.

With regards to my strength I consider myself slightly above average. I can do 10 proper pullups, 15 chinups, 60+ pushups, ~20 dips.

I acknowledge that my greatest weakness is lack of stamina. I can barely run 2km. This lack plus weak asthma(I breathe really heavily after just warming up, but I'm not tired?).

At what point am I fit enough to pursue boxing. What fitness programs out there cater to my weakness to help me improve to that level of fitness.

Comment: Depends on the level they're willing to train.  Most public boxing gyms will take you from wherever you're at.  Sounds like you're fit enough to me.

Comment: If as you say you can barely run 1.2 miles, and you have a medical condition, perhaps it's time to speak to a medical professional. I hope you get the all-clear, but see your doctor. I agree you've got the other stuff covered.

Answer (score 5):

You seem already more than fit enough. Everyone will have their own weaknesses, be it strength, stamina, balance, flexibility, or whathaveyou. All the boxing or kickboxing programs I've seen have warmup and conditioning parts to their classes/sessions. They involve rope jumping, calisthenics, shadow boxing, bag hitting, stretching, etc. Doing those, over time, will improve your stamina. So will doing the boxing rounds themselves.

So I'd say "go for it!" I can do a lot less pure strength exercises than you, and have no especial stamina, yet I kickbox without any problems.

Just pace yourself and stay safe. Don't let ego or beginner's exuberance push you to go beyond what you can safely do. Take breaks and stand to the side as you feel you need to.

Answer (score 4):

This is also a question people struggle with when wanting to return to training after a break, where it can be a bigger problem because going back in at their old level means a certain intensity from their peers.  Regardless of whether taking up something new or returning to an old activity, the bottom line is participation and determination.  However tough it is initially, and wherever you are relative to those around you, if you keep going a few times a week and trying hard and with directed purpose you'll quickly get the strength and stamina required.  Flexibility is not guaranteed just by attendance and effort - you really have to direct time at it, but that's less of a concern for boxing than for many other fighting sports and arts.

Don't waste time worrying and waiting... just train.